# Show that $f(x) \to +\infty$ knowing that $xf'(x) \to 1$ when $x \to +\infty$, $f$ being differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let be $f : \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous and differentiable function.

Let's suppose that $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} xf'(x) = 1$. I have to prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$.

What I tried:

- First, we can see that the hypothesis can be rewritten as $f'(x) \sim \dfrac{1}{x}$, we know then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$.

**Idea** : Formally, it seems like if I can integrate $f'(x)$, I could get "$f(x) \sim \ln x \to +\infty$" (**I know we cannot integrate $o$ asymptotic terms.**)

- Second, I'd try to use Taylor formulas, but as $f$ is only **derivable**, $\int_{0}^{x} f'(t) \textrm{d}t$ is not even defined… (we cannot use any kind of advanced integration such as Lesbegue, etc. Riemann integrals only.)

Hôpital's Rule is unavailable.

Comment: Mean value theorem. $f(n+1) - f(n) \geqslant \frac{1}{2(n+1)}$ for all large enough $n$. And $f$ is eventually increasing.

Comment: I understand that $f$ is eventually increasing due to $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x$ sufficiently large. But, how did you get the lower bound?

Comment: What does the mean value theorem tell you about $f(n+1) - f(n)$?

Comment: There is a $c \in ]n, n + 1[$ such that $f'(c) = f(n + 1) - f(n)$? I don't understand how can I say $f'(c) \geq \dfrac{1}{2(n + 1)}$ for all large enough $n$.

Comment: From $xf'(x) \to 1$, there is an $x_0$ such that $xf'(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for $x \geqslant x_0$. Then, if $n \geqslant x_0$ …

Comment: @DanielFischer … Thank you, that was a nice refresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem suffices to deduce $f(x) \sim \ln x$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $x_{\varepsilon}$ such that $1-\varepsilon \leqslant xf'(x) \leqslant 1 + \varepsilon$ for $x \geqslant x_{\varepsilon}$. By the mean value theorem we have

$$ f(x+1) - f(x) = f'(\xi_n)$$

for some $\xi_n \in \mathopen]x,x+1\mathclose[$. Then, for $n \geqslant x_{\varepsilon}$ it follows that

$$\frac{1-\varepsilon}{n+1} \leqslant f(n+1) - f(n) \leqslant \frac{1+\varepsilon}{n}$$

and hence

$$(1-\varepsilon)\sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{1}{n+k} \leqslant f(n+m) - f(n) \leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n+k}.$$

Thus, using the asymptotics of the harmonic numbers and the eventual monotonicity of $f$, there are constants $K_1,K_2$ such that

$$K_1 + (1-\varepsilon) \ln x \leqslant f(x) \leqslant K_2 + (1+\varepsilon)\ln x$$

for all $x \geqslant x_{\varepsilon}$.